# Flask WTForms - Is it possible to use step parameter for allowing setting seconds in TimeField?

Tags: python, flask, time, input-field

I've just discovered the existence of `wtforms.fields.html5` with `TimeField`, `DateField` etc. inside.

Normally in HTML one would write the following

```
<input type="time" step="1"/>
```

to render a field for setting time.

Since I'm generating a form (with various `<input/>` fields incl. one for time) in Python I'm struggling to find a way to set the `step` parameter.

I tried adding an extra argument to the constructor called `step` just to check if it exists. Didn't work, doesn't exist.

In addition I tried setting the format:

```
task_clock_due = TimeField('Time due',
                           validators=[validators.InputRequired()],
                           format='%H:%M:%S'
                           )
```

Since the format includes hours, minutes and seconds I was actually expecting the time field to get the seconds part too. Apparently it doesn't work like this. I would still get the seconds, whenever I submit the value but it's always `00` and the user has no way of actually interacting with the seconds.

I went as deep as checking the source code of the specific widget but nothing came out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. Apparently there is the `render_kw` argument, which can also be used - for example - in a `TextField` to set the placeholder to a specific value.

The solution:

```
task_clock_due = TimeField('Time due',
                           validators=[validators.InputRequired()],
                           format='%H:%M:%S',
                           render_kw={"step": "1"}
                           )
```